# Django and Bootstrap: prevent warning box from appearing if there is an empty string

Tags: django, bootstrap-4, django-views, django-templates

I'm using Django templates and Bootstrap to render a red alert box if there is a `message`.  The code is:

**views.py**

```
else:
    return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
        'listing': listing,
        'form': BidForm(),
        'message': '',
        'comments': listing.comments.all()
    })
```

**listing.html**

```
<div>
    <p>Starting Bid: {{ listing.starting_bid}}</p>
    <p>Current Bid: {{ listing.price }}</p>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: inline-block;">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The red warning box renders if there is no message (i.e. an empty string), which seems sensible and intuitive.  However,  when I ***remove*** `message` from views.py altogether, the red warning box still renders.

```
    else:
        return render(request, 'auctions/listing.html', {
            'listing': listing,
            'form': BidForm(),
#            'message': '',
            'comments': listing.comments.all()
        })
```

What am I doing wrong here?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check if `message` is not empty and then only show it.

This code shows the alert only  if `message` is not empty.

```
{% if message %}
<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: inline-block;">
        {{ message }}
    </div>
{% endif %}
```